# Get a list of all tree nodes (in all levels) in TreeView Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

How can I get a list of all tree nodes (in all levels) in a `TreeView` control?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have a tree with one root node the following code will always loop the tree nodes down to the deepest, then go one level back and so on. It will print the text of each node.
(Untested from the top of my head)

```
TreeNode oMainNode = oYourTreeView.Nodes[0];
PrintNodesRecursive(oMainNode);

public void PrintNodesRecursive(TreeNode oParentNode)
{
  Console.WriteLine(oParentNode.Text);

  // Start recursion on all subnodes.
  foreach(TreeNode oSubNode in oParentNode.Nodes)
  {
    PrintNodesRecursive(oSubNode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use two recursive extension methods. You can either call `myTreeView.GetAllNodes()` or `myTreeNode.GetAllNodes()`:

```
public static List<TreeNode> GetAllNodes(this TreeView _self)
{
    List<TreeNode> result = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (TreeNode child in _self.Nodes)
    {
        result.AddRange(child.GetAllNodes());
    }
    return result;
}

public static List<TreeNode> GetAllNodes(this TreeNode _self)
{
    List<TreeNode> result = new List<TreeNode>();
    result.Add(_self);
    foreach (TreeNode child in _self.Nodes)
    {
        result.AddRange(child.GetAllNodes());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: runs for me changing `_self.ChildNodes` by `_self.Nodes`. Remember to write this two methods into a new static class: `public static class TreeViewExtensions`.

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks, I fixed the mistake. Not sure why I used `ChildNodes` in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Lazy LINQ approach, just in case you're looking for something like this:

```
private void EnumerateAllNodes()
{
    TreeView myTree = ...;

    var allNodes = myTree.Nodes
        .Cast<TreeNode>()
        .SelectMany(GetNodeBranch);

    foreach (var treeNode in allNodes)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

private IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetNodeBranch(TreeNode node)
{
    yield return node;

    foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
        foreach (var childChild in GetNodeBranch(child))
            yield return childChild;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Update to Krumelur's answer (replace 2 first lines of his/her solution with this):

```
foreach ( var node in oYourTreeView.Nodes )
{
    PrintNodesRecursive( node );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, then it will spit out all subtrees if there are several roots. But really: a tree with several nodes is a really seldom in nature :-)
Oh, and it's "his" ;)

Comment: In fact, in nature this is a quite common phaenommena :)
In programming I can imagine a few scenarios where it is useful. For example: treeview containing departments of a company, each having subdepartments and so on. You probably won't have any superdepartment.

Comment: Sorry guys but you both need to edit your answers. @Krumelur your foreach is misspelled and dzendras, your 'var' is not correct. Shouldn't it be a cast of somesort to TreeNode? In C# var is not recognised.

Comment: Though it is true that var is recognized by the new C# compiler, it has to know the type to work correctly and Nodes is IEnumerable, not IEnumerable<TreeNode> and so will be typed as object.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the node Key to be unique, just set all of the node keys to an empty string (`""`), then you can do a `Treeview1.Nodes.Find("", true);` to return all nodes within a TreeView.

Answer (score 2):

If you need some processing across all nodes of a treeview, you could use a stack rather than recursive methods:

```
Stack<TreeNode> nodeStack = new Stack<TreeNode>(treeview1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>());
while(nodeStack.Count > 0)
{
   TreeNode node = nodeStack.Pop();

   // Do your processing on the node here...

   // Add all children to the stack
   if(node.Nodes.Count > 0)
     foreach(TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
        nodeStack.Push(child);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because TreeView has many levels, do recursive function:

```
   public void AddNodeAndChildNodesToList(TreeNode node)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(node.Text);    // Adding current nodename to ListBox     

        foreach (TreeNode actualNode in node.Nodes)
        {
            AddNodeAndChildNodesToList(actualNode); // recursive call
        }
    }
```

Than call this function for all first level Nodes in TreeView:

```
    foreach (TreeNode actualNode in treeView1.Nodes)         // Begin with Nodes from TreeView
    {
         AddNodeAndChildNodesToList(actualNode);
    }
```

Code is from site [C# TreeView](http://c-treeview.com/TreeView-Get-All-Child-Nodes.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think my solution is more elegant, it uses generics (because TreeView can store each kind of objects derived from TreeNode) and has a single function recursively called.
It should be straightforward also convert this as extension.

```
    List<T> EnumerateAllTreeNodes<T>(TreeView tree, T parentNode = null) where T : TreeNode
    {
        if (parentNode != null && parentNode.Nodes.Count == 0)
            return new List<T>() { };

        TreeNodeCollection nodes = parentNode != null ? parentNode.Nodes : tree.Nodes;
        List<T> childList = nodes.Cast<T>().ToList();

        List<T> result = new List<T>(1024); //Preallocate space for children
        result.AddRange(childList); //Level first

        //Recursion on each child node
        childList.ForEach(n => result.AddRange(EnumerateAllTreeNodes(tree,n)));

        return result;
    }
```

The usage is straightforward, just call:

```
    List<MyNodeType> allnodes = EnumerateAllTreeNodes<MyNodeType>(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code help you to iterate though all TreeView list with identifying current depth level. Code can be used to save TreeView items to XML file and other purposes.

```
int _level = 0;
        TreeNode _currentNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
        do
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_currentNode.Text + " " + _level);
            if (_currentNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                _currentNode = _currentNode.Nodes[0];
                _level++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_currentNode.NextNode != null)
                    _currentNode = _currentNode.NextNode;
                else
                {
                    _currentNode = _currentNode.Parent.NextNode;
                    _level--;
                }
            }
        }
        while (_level > 0);
```