# C# Select TreeNode by Tag from DataGridViewRow index

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, treeview

**BACKGROUND**

I have a `DataGridView` table that populates a `TreeView` with `TreeNodes`. The `TreeNode.Tag` property value is determined by the table `RowIndex`. When I select a `Cell` in the table the `TreeView` node with the selected tablerowindex as tag should also be selected and it's parent expanded.

But how do I get the nodes tag value and compare it to the `RowIndex`? I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360956/5825579) extention method to get all `TreeNode` objects from the `TreeView` as follows

```
var select = from node in treeView.Descendants()
             where (node.Tag as string) == e.RowIndex.ToString()
             select node as TreeNode;
```

But `var select` return an empty `WhereSelectListIterator`? Where did I go wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

The `TreeNode` where `TreeNode.Tag` is the `IndexRow` is at `TreeNode.Level` 3 and the `Descendants()` method only return root level nodes and root level child nodes, and that is why my `WhereSelectListIterator` is empty.

The question is now How do I get the `Descendants()` method to include `TreeNodes` at `TreeNode.Level` 3?

**UPDATE 2**

Instead of using the `Descendants()` method I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24856090/5825579) extention method to get a list of all `TreeNodes` in `TreeView` and it included all nodes no matter what level.

But now I cannot compare the `node.Tag` to the `e.RowIndex`?

The method this far:

```
private void headerGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TreeNode> oNodeList = treeView.GetAllNodes();

        var select = from node in oNodeList
                     where (node.Tag as string) == e.RowIndex.ToString()
                     select node as TreeNode;
        foreach (TreeNode node in select)
        {
            // This never happens because the select is empty
        }
    }
```

I tested the oNodeList like this so I know(!) there is nodes with tags in the list.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (TreeNode node in oNodeList)
{
    if (node.Tag != null) sb.AppendLine(node.Name);
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution to my problem. There is really no need to use Linq to select nodes and add to a WhereSelectListIterator. The solution was much simpler than that.

```
private void headerGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    List<TreeNode> oNodeList = treeView.GetAllNodes();
    foreach (TreeNode node in oNodeList)
    {
        if (node.Tag == null) continue;
        if ((int)node.Tag == e.RowIndex)
        {
            treeView.SelectedNode = node;
            if (!treeView.SelectedNode.Parent.IsExpanded) treeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Expand();
        }
    }
}
```

**CONCLUTION**

Don't over complicate things.

Comment: This question is asked a lot.  You really need to create a dictionary between the rows of the DGV and the nodes in the TreeNode to get a cross reference.

Comment: @jdweng Can you please give an example or link to an answer to the question? I am not sure how to set up the dictionary as a cross reference.