# How do I find all TreeNodes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I want to access all treenodes of this tree:
[image]
and I used this code:

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(node.Text);
                }
```

but it only lists the MSI motherboard.

How do I get all nodes?

Comment: recursively get them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of all tree nodes (in all levels) in TreeView Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702051/get-a-list-of-all-tree-nodes-in-all-levels-in-treeview-controls)

Comment: Visual studio doesn't have a defnition for .GetAllNodes()

Comment: which platform are you using? winform, wpf, asp.net webform, or others?

Comment: winforms, sorry for dispearing and thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. Lei Yang was right but I didn't know what "recursively" meant. This is the solution:

```
private void DrawConnects(TreeNode node)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
        {
            if (child.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(child.Parent); //Do what you want to do with the nodes here
                DrawConnects(child);
            } else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(child.Parent); // And here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your accessing only the first layer of your node.
You have to go into the Nodes of your first Node.

maybe with:

```cs
TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
                foreach (TreeNode node in nodes.Nodes)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(node.Text);
                }
```