# Converting TreeNode to DataTable Dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, treenode

There are plenty of methods to convert datatable into treeview (treenode) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805457/populate-winfrom-treeview-from-datatable). But is there any way to do create a datatable maintaining hierarchy. For ex. if `TreeNode` is like

```
A-A1
 -A2-A21
    -A22
B-B1
 -B2-B21
 -B3-B31
    -B32-B321
        -B322
    -B33
 -B4
```

should look like following in datatable. Then i can either save it in the databse or show it to the user in a `datagrid`.

[image]

All column  can have take `string` values.

Is there any way so i can pass a `treenode` to a function & it will create datatble like this dynamically. `treenode` structure will change everytime that's why i can not hardcode it. Suppose i have a recursive function like this.

```
public void CreateData(TreeNode trn)
{

   foreach(TreeNode t in trn.Nodes)
   {
       CreateData(t);
   }

}
```

i am facing difficulty in understanding flow of code for recursive function.
any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean save to DataTable or to DataBase? Anyway, what structue may this datatable have. According to your exmple may this dataTable have one column (type string) or shall this table have multiple (dynamically created) columns (type string). Please add some more information!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462

Comment: Hippo generally in these cases you have a table with lets say ID, caption and ParentID and each non root node has parentID pointing to its parent node record in the table. I think you should go this way and not with a table like the one you have defined in your question. also consider that there are treeview controls able to populate exactly in this way when you bind them to such table structure like I mentioned.

Comment: Edited the question, have a look.

Comment: After your edit: your point of departure is still not clear. What is the source of your data?  Do you already have hierarchical data stored somewhere and you just want to create a `System.Data.DataTable` dynamically? But then, what do you mean by "save it in the database"?

Comment: i want to display data in tabular form  & thats why i need to save it in structure like datatbale or dataset so that i can show it to the user in a DataGrid. In future i might want to convert this datatable into database but for the time being showing it in the DataGrid will fulfill my requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pseudo code, hope it will help you to deal with your problem

```
private void getNodeList()
{
    //This will hold your node text
    List<string> nodeTextList = new List<string>();
    //loop through all teeview nodes
    foreach(TreeNode rootNode in treeView.Nodes)
    {
       //Add root node to list
       nodeTextList.Add(rootNode.Text);
       //Do recursive getter to get child nodes of root node
       getChildNodes(rootNode, nodeTextList);

    }
    //Do with nodeTextList what ever you want, for example add to datatable.
}

private void getChildNodes(TreeNode rootNode, List<string> nodeTextList)
{
   foreach(TreeNode childNode in rootNode.Nodes)
   {
       //Add child node text
       nodeTextList.Add(childNode.Text);      
       getChildNodes(childNode, nodeTextList);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo code but `NodeTextList` just fetches the names of all nodes present in the Node. There is no way i can maintain child parent relationship.

Comment: create class to hold child and parent, make list of that class and fill it

Answer (score 0):

If you cann't understand that function or how it should work, you might want to read about `Depth-first search`. Its exacly what you're doing + you should add code that save the node you're in at moment.