# How to insert Datas to the Winform TreeView(C#) in effitive coding?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, treeview

I am using Winform C# and MySQL.

I have table with columns name and parent id.

I got solution,.. But its too big and each and every time I want to change this code.

Please help me to add the data's with parent id. In Simple Format.

```
string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["College_Management_System.Properties.Settings.cmsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                MySqlDataReader Reader;
                command.CommandText = "select * from menu_details";
                connection.Open();
                Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(0))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(1))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(2))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(3))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(4))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[3].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(7))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(8))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(9))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[2].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }

                    if (Reader[2].ToString() == Convert.ToString(29))
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[3].Nodes.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch { }
```

**Updated Question -**

I try Eswarn,..

Below Format is not Working Properly@!

```
dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1", "One", null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "2", "Two", null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "3", "Three", "2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "4", "Four", "1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "5", "Five", "4" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "6", "Six", "2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "7", "Seven", "1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "8", "Eight", "7" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "9", "Nine", "8" });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Parse the value of `Reader[2]` to avoid String-comparison (always use `.Equals()` IF you do!!!!) and use a switch statement:

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
  TreeNodeCollection parent;
  int readValue = Int32.Parse(Reader[2].ToString);
  switch(readValue)
  {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      parent = treeView1.Nodes[readValue-1].Nodes;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      parent = treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[readValue-7].Nodes;
      break;
    case 29:
      parent = treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes[3].Nodes;
      break;
    default:
      parent = treeView1.Nodes;
      break;
  }

  parent.Add(Reader[3].ToString(), Reader[1].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is populating treeview with XML. You Can change this on MySQL too..

```
private void populateBaseNodes()
{
    treeViewMenu.Nodes.Clear(); // Clear any existing items
    treeViewMenu.BeginUpdate(); // Begin updating the treeview
    TreeNode treenode;
    treenode = treeViewMenu.Nodes.Add("Folders");

    XmlNodeList baseNodeList = docXML.SelectNodes("root/folder");
    // Get all first level <folder> nodes

    foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in baseNodeList)
    // loop through all base <folder> nodes 
    {
        string title = xmlnode.Attributes["title"].Value;

        treenode = treeViewMenu.Nodes.Add(title); // add it to the tree

        populateChildNodes(xmlnode, treenode); // Get the children
    }

    treeViewMenu.EndUpdate(); // Stop updating the tree
    treeViewMenu.Refresh(); // refresh the treeview display
}

private void populateChildNodes(XmlNode oldXmlnode, TreeNode oldTreenode)
{
    TreeNode treenode = null;
    XmlNodeList childNodeList = oldXmlnode.ChildNodes;
    // Get all children for the past node (parent)

    foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in childNodeList)
    // loop through all children
    {
        string title = xmlnode.Attributes["title"].Value;
        // add it to the parent node tree
        treenode = oldTreenode.Nodes.Add(title);
        populateChildNodes(xmlnode, treenode); 
    }
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42272/Populate-TreeView-Menu-with-XML

Comment: Its difficult to understand this. Can Anyone change this in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new class to represent your database records:**

I have used the naming convention from the Add method on the TreeNodeCollection, where Key is the node value, and Text is the node label, because you haven't made it clear what the columns in your table are actually called or what types they are. It would be useful if you could add this information to the question.

```
public class TreeNodeRecord
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string ParentKey { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Typically Key would be the primary key value (usually called  something like ID) from the database. ParentKey would be the primary key value of the parent node (usually stored in a column called something like ParentId). Your code appears to link the nodes together in this way, which is the most common implementation of storing a tree in a database.

So for example:

- a TreeNodeRecord where Key = 1 and ParentKey = 0 is the root node
- a TreeNodeRecord where Key = 2 and ParentKey = 1 is a child of the root node.

**Create a class to encapsulate the methods for filling a treeview with nodes from your database:**

```
public static class TreeBuilder
{
    public static void BuildTree(TreeView treeview)
    {
        // Load database records into strongly typed list
        List<TreeNodeRecord> records = GetTreeNodeRecords();

        //Pause redrawing for the tree view control
        treeview.BeginUpdate();
        // Recursively add all items in the list to the tree
        AddNodes(records, "0", treeview.Nodes);
        // Resume redrawing for the tree view control
        treeview.EndUpdate();
    }

    // A method that reads all of the database records, and returns a strongly typed list for further processing
    private static List<TreeNodeRecord> GetTreeNodeRecords()
    {
        List<TreeNodeRecord> records = new List<TreeNodeRecord>();

        string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["College_Management_System.Properties.Settings.cmsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                MySqlDataReader reader;
                command.CommandText = "select * from menu_details";

                using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        TreeNodeRecord newRecord = new TreeNodeRecord
                        {
                            Key = reader[3].ToString(),
                            ParentKey = reader[2].ToString(),
                            Name = reader[1].ToString()
                        };
                        records.Add(newRecord);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return records;
    }

    // A recursive method to add nodes to the tree
    private static void AddNodes(List<TreeNodeRecord> records, string parentKey, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        List<TreeNodeRecord> children = records.Where(r => r.ParentKey == parentKey).ToList();

        foreach (TreeNodeRecord child in children)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = nodes.Add(child.Key, child.Text);
            AddNodes(records, child.Key, newNode.Nodes);
        }

    }
}
```

**Use the class to populate your TreeView control:**

```
TreeBuilder.BuildTree(treeView1);
```

Please note it is important to dispose of your objects correctly. If an object you are using implements IDisposable (has a Dispose() method), you should call Dispose() when you are finished with it. The above code achieves this by wrapping the objects in using statements, which ensures Dispose() is called even if any exceptions are raised.

Comment: Thanks sga. I will implement this.

Comment: Only parents added in Treeview. The Child are not added. what this Key refers ?.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain what each value is. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement and tell you