# System.Collections.Generic.List<ActualEstimatation.frmEstimate.ItemInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: winforms, treeview

I am trying to bind treeview dynamically.

I Searched in Google and found some good links.

When I try to run in my system its showing error something like this

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<ActualEstimatation.frmEstimate.ItemInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ActualEstimatation.frmEstimate.ItemInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Those links are
[How to dynamically populate treeview (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814466/how-to-dynamically-populate-treeview-c)

and sga101's Solutions
[How to insert Datas to the Winform TreeView(C#) in effitive coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044104/how-to-insert-datas-to-the-winform-treeviewc-in-effitive-coding)

I searched in Google to solve the above issue but not found any solution.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using .net framework 3.5 or higher?

Comment: yes, I am using .net Framework3.5

Comment: Enumerable.Where() is an *extension method*.  Put `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source code file.

Answer (score 0):

i need to see more of your code but i believe what you are missing is LINQ statement.
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) you can read about it and start to see how to implement in your application.

for example:

```
using (ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
{
   var query_where1 = from a in svcContext.AccountSet
                where a.Name.Contains("Contoso")
                select a;
   foreach (var a in query_where1)
   {
    System.Console.WriteLine(a.Name + " " + a.Address1_City);
   }
}
```