# Populate TreeView from DataTable or List that contains tree-like data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, treeview

I have created an account table in my database, with these columns:

```
ID
Name
ParentID
```

This is an example of how records have been stored:

```
ID   Name    ParentID
1    BANK A  0
2    0001    1
3    0002    1
4    BANK B  0
5    0001    4
6    0002    4
```

But the company name does not come from database, it comes from code. So how can I expand the `TreeView` like this?

```
├─ BANK A
│  ├─ 0001
│  └─ 0002
└─ BANK B
   ├─ 0001
   └─ 0002
```

How can I do this in C#? I also tried from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805457/populate-winforms-treeview-from-datatable) but I still don't understand it.

Answer (score 7):

i have found a piece of code that worked great for me after spending 2h to make complicated algorithlms :

```
 //In Page load
 //select where id is null to retrieve the parent nodes 
 //in a datatable (called table here)
 foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
 {
   TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
   node.Text = row["title"].ToString();
   node.Value = row["id"].ToString();
   //you can affect the node.NavigateUrl

   node.PopulateOnDemand = true;
   TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
 }
```

then create the TreeNodePopulate event :

```
 protected void TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
 {
     string id= e.Node.Value;
     //do your "select from yourTable where parentId =" + id;

     foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
     {
         TreeNode node = new TreeNode(row["title"], row["id"])
         node.PopulateOnDemand = true;    
         e.Node.ChildNodes.Add(node);
     }

 }
```

it worked like hell for me, i hope it will help !

Comment: Code is either missing, or in error: A WinForm TreeView TreeNode has no 'PopulateOnDemand property.

Comment: This code is nearly 6 years old, you may need to find a equivalent method. I haven't touched C# since.

Comment: 'PopulateOnDemand is in System.Web.UI.WebControls this is  a WinForm question.

Comment: The event "TreeNodePopulate" is too good to be true in the case of WinForms. Most form designers will pick up on that right away. For those reading.. @BillW explained.

Answer (score 3):

To populate a `TreeView` from a `DataTable` or any `IEnumerable<T>`, you should be able to answer the following questions:

1. What are data source items
2. How to detect if an item in data source is a root item in tree
3. How to find child items of an item in data source
4. How to create tree item from data source item.

By passing answer of above questions as lambda expressions to the following method, it uses a recursive algorithm to create a list of `TreeNode` which you can add to `TreeView`. Each `TreeNode` contains the descendant `TreeNode` items:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetTreeNodes<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, Boolean> isRoot,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> getChilds,
    Func<T, TreeNode> getItem)
{
    IEnumerable<T> roots = source.Where(x => isRoot(x));
    foreach (T root in roots)
        yield return ConvertEntityToTreeNode(root, source, getChilds, getItem); ;
}

private TreeNode ConvertEntityToTreeNode<T>(
    T entity,
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> getChilds,
    Func<T, TreeNode> getItem)
{
    TreeNode node = getItem(entity);
    var childs = getChilds(entity, source);
    foreach (T child in childs)
        node.Nodes.Add(ConvertEntityToTreeNode(child, source, getChilds, getItem));
    return node;
}
```

**Example**

I assume you have loaded data into the following structure:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "Menu 1", DBNull.Value);
dt.Rows.Add(11, "Menu 1-1", 1);
dt.Rows.Add(111, "Menu 1-1-1", 11);
dt.Rows.Add(112, "Menu 1-1-2", 11);
dt.Rows.Add(12, "Menu 1-2", 1);
dt.Rows.Add(121, "Menu 1-2-1", 12);
dt.Rows.Add(122, "Menu 1-2-2", 12);
dt.Rows.Add(123, "Menu 1-2-3", 12);
dt.Rows.Add(124, "Menu 1-2-4", 12);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Menu 2", DBNull.Value);
dt.Rows.Add(21, "Menu 2-1", 2);
dt.Rows.Add(211, "Menu 2-1-1", 21);
```

Then to convert it nodes of a `TreeView`, you can use the following code:

```
var source = dt.AsEnumerable();
var nodes = GetTreeNodes(
        source,
        (r) => r.Field<int?>("ParentId") == null,
        (r, s) => s.Where(x => r["Id"].Equals(x["ParentId"])),
        (r) => new TreeNode { Text = r.Field<string>("Name") }
);
treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(nodes.ToArray());
```

As a result, you will have the following tree structure:

```
├─ Menu 1
│  ├─ Menu 1-1
│  │  ├─ Menu 1-1-1
│  │  └─ Menu 1-1-2
│  └─ Menu 1-2
│     ├─ Menu 1-2-1
│     ├─ Menu 1-2-2
│     ├─ Menu 1-2-3
│     └─ Menu 1-2-4
└─ Menu 2
   └─ Menu 2-1
      └─ Menu 2-1-1
```