# How to loop through an object list which has a list of the same type and add each object to TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

The title may not be very clear but I will try to explain more here...

I have the following class...

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<Node> Children { get; set; } = new List<Node>();

    public Node(string name, List<Node> children)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = children;
    }

    public Node() {  }
}
```

And I have a **TreeView** that should elements like this...

```
- Root
    - Node 0_0
        - Node 1_0
            - Node 2_0
        - Node 1_1
    - Node 0_1
        - Node 1_0
        - Node 1_1
```

And so on...

Currently, I use this inefficient, bad, pyramid-of-doom approach...

```
var rootNode = GetNodeFromString();

var rootTreeNode = TreeView1.Items.Add(new TreeNode(rootNode.Name));

foreach (var child0 in rootNode.Children)
{       
    var node1 = rootTreeNode.Items.Add(new TreeNode(child0.Name));  

    foreach (var child1 in node1.Children)
    {
        node1.Items.Add(new TreeNode(child1.Name));

        // Repeat the code 30 more times...
    }
}
```

Is there's any other way I can achieve unlimited depth? (***not really unlimited, something like 128 layers***)

Comment: You can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924862/3110834), a generic method which helps you to populate a `TreeView` from a `DataTable` or any `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, but still that answer has some stuff that I can't seem to be able to figure out correctly... what's that Func<> isRoot?

Comment: @RezaAghaei is there's a way you can modify that function to remove to make it more automatic? and remember that I don't load from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out a way myself to do this in **11 lines**...

```
public static TreeNode ToTreeNode(Node root)
{
    var treeNode = new TreeNode(root.Name);

    foreach (var node in root.Children)
    {
        treeNode.Nodes.Add(ToTreeNode(node));
    }

    return treeNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Generic Solution**

You can create a generic method like this:

```
private TreeNode ConvertEntityToTreeNode<T>(
    T entity,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChilds,
    Func<T, TreeNode> createTreeNode)
{
    TreeNode node = createTreeNode(entity);
    var childs = getChilds(entity);
    foreach (T child in childs)
        node.Nodes.Add(ConvertEntityToTreeNode(child, getChilds, createTreeNode));
    return node;
}
```

- `entity`: The entity which is going to be root in the tree hierarchy.
- `getChilds`: The expression to get the children from a node.
- `createTreeNode`: The expression to create a `TreeNode` from the entity.

Then use it this way:

```
var treeNode = ConvertEntityToTreeNode(node, x => x.Children, x => new TreeNode(x.Name));
treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
```

**Non-Generic Solution**

You have already found it yourself. It's quite easy and straightforward:

```
private TreeNode ConvertEntityToTreeNode(Node entity)
{
    var node = new TreeNode(entity.Name);
    foreach (var child in entity.Children)
        node.Nodes.Add(ConvertEntityToTreeNode(child));
    return node;
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
var treeNode = ConvertEntityToTreeNode(node);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
```

**Why you may want a generic solution?**

Just in case you have a couple of node classes and trees. The algorithm of creation is always the same, you just need to know:

1. The root object
2. How to get children of an object
3. How to create a `TreeNode` using an object

Then the algorithm is always a recursive algorithm which you see in the generic method.

Comment: Why you may want a generic solution? Just in case you have a couple of node classes and trees. The algorithm of creation is always the same, you just need to know the 1)Root object  2)How to get children of an object 3) How to create a `TreeNode` using an object. Then the algorithm is always a recursive algorithm which you see in the generic method.