# Convert tree-like class data structure to Winforms TreeView for ease of debugging visually

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, tree

Using C#, I have created a "node" class (which contains a `List` of type itself) to allow for recursive tree-like data structures. This is a simplified version of the class:

```
public class node
{
    public List<node> c = null;
    public int data = 0;

    public node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I've come across a point in my program where it's getting very hard to debug due to the nature of trees. Large trees especially are difficult to probe visually.

For this reason, I had the brain wave to use Winform's `TreeView` control to display the data so I can more easily visualize what's going on. I understand and have implemented preorder and inorder traversal for a minimax algorithm, and so I was wondering if I could utilize some of that code to help with converting from my own node tree to a `TreeView` tree.

The method skeleton would look like this:

```
private void convertNodetreetoTreeview(node n)
{
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode("Root node");
    
    ...

    treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
}
```

How would I go about this?

For speed, I would prefer an iterative solution, but a recursive solution would be fine too.

Comment: *I have created a "node" class* - I do wish you'd created it using c# naming conventions..

Comment: This may help: [Populate TreeView from DataTable or List that contains tree-like data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924862/3110834)

Comment: @CaiusJard: Oh you just mean capitalize the 'N' ? I like using lowercase so as to differentiate my custom classes from official C# classes/methods. So all of mine are lowercase in that way. Bear in mind, I can distinguish such class names visually from standard variables, because they're light blue instead of black.

Comment: As an idea you can also [Create a custom data visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to use in Visual Studio to visualize your data at debug-time.

Answer (score 1):

I take the following statement and as I mentioned in the comments, as an idea you can also [Create a custom data visualizer to use in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to visualize your data at debug-time.

> for ease of debugging visually

Then, when you are debugging your application wherever you have a breakpoint for the node class, you will see the visualizer icon:

[image]

And if you click on it, you can see your custom visualizer, which could be a Form containing a TreeView:

[image]

#### Create a custom debugger visualizer for my tree-like data structure

There are a few nice articles and guides in Microsoft Docs which explains the architecture of the visualizers and teach you how to create an install a simple visualizer. Here I also put a very simplified guideline to show you how you can achieve what I showed in above screenshots:

1. Create a .NET Framework Class Library for you data class. Name the project `MyDataObjects`. This project will contain your data objects which you want to create a custom visualizer for them. Here, `Node` class. Use the same node class in your main project as well.
2. Add the following `Node.cs` class to it:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   namespace MyDataObjects
   {
       [Serializable]
       public class Node
       {
           private Node() { }
           public List<Node> Nodes { get; } = new List<Node>();
           public string Text { get; set; }
           public Node(string data)
           {
               this.Text = data;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a .NET Framework Class Library for you visualizer. Name the project `MyDataObjectsVisualizers`.
4. Add reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll` which you can browse from:

- `<Visual Studio Install Directory>\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

5. Add reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` which you can find in framework assemblies.
6. Add the following `NodeExtensions.cs` class to it:

   ```
   using MyDataObjects;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace MyDataObjectsVisualizers
   {
       public static class NodeExtensions
       {
           public static TreeNode ToTreeNode(this Node node)
           {
               var treeNode = new TreeNode(node.Text);
               foreach (Node child in node.Nodes)
                   treeNode.Nodes.Add(child.ToTreeNode());
               return treeNode;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. Add a new form to the project and name it `NodeVisualizerForm.cs`. Drop a `TreeView` on the form and set its `Dock` to `Fill`. Then add the following code to the form:

   ```
   using MyDataObjects;
   using System;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace MyDataObjectsVisualizers
   {
       public partial class NodeVisualizerForm : Form
       {
           public NodeVisualizerForm()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }
           public Node Node { get; set; }
           protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
           {
               base.OnLoad(e);
               if (Node != null)
                   treeView1.Nodes.Add(Node.ToTreeNode());
           }
       }
   }
   ```
8. Add a `DebuggerSide.cs` class to the project with the following code:

   ```
   using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;

   [assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
       typeof(MyDataObjectsVisualizers.DebuggerSide),
       typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
       Target = typeof(MyDataObjects.Node),
       Description = "Sample Visualizer")]

   namespace MyDataObjectsVisualizers
   {
       public class DebuggerSide : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
       {
           protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService,
               IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
           {
               var node = objectProvider.GetObject() as MyDataObjects.Node;
               var form = new NodeVisualizerForm();
               form.Node = node;
               windowService.ShowDialog(form);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
9. Build the solution, and copy the following files to the following locations:

- Copy `MyDataObjectsVisualizers.dll` to:
  `[VS Installation Folder]\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`
- Copy `MyDataObjects.dll` to:
  `[VS Installation Folder]\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\netstandard2.0`

10. Then close all visual studio instances. Then open the solution which you ant to debug and set a breakpoint for node, and run the application. There you go! You can see the visualizer icon (the magnifier) close to the node, like what I showed in the screenshot above and by clicking on it, you will see the visualizer form.

Please take note, in the main project, you should use the same `Node` dll that we created in `MyDataObjects` project.

**More information:**

- [Walkthrough: Writing a Visualizer in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-writing-a-visualizer-in-csharp?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: Install a Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-install-a-visualizer?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Create custom data visualizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: That's quite a lot of code and setting up relative to my solution, but you know what - if I have trouble implementing non-recursive alpha-beta pruning or iterative deepening, and I need to step through the code line by line, your solution may just save the day, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to go about just what you're asking for. Instead of utilizing a `Stack` and a List (as you might for usual preorder traversal), you utilize TWO stacks - one for the `node` tree you have, and one for the `TreeView` tree. From there, it's a simple case of pushing TreeView nodes when custom `node`s are being pushed, and popping TreeView nodes when your custom `node`s are being popped. Whilst you're pushing TreeView nodes, you simultaneously add these nodes to the TreeView using the top-most TreeView stack reference.

Feel free to replace the `mystringdata` variable with one of your choice.

```
private void convertNodetreeToTreeview(node n)
{
    Stack<node> stack1 = new Stack<node>();
    Stack<TreeNode> stack2 = new Stack<TreeNode>();                     

    stack1.Push(n);
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode( n.mystringdata );
    stack2.Push(root);

    while (stack1.Count > 0)
    {
        node t = stack1.Pop();
        TreeNode r = stack2.Pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < t.c.Count; i++)
        {
            if (t.c[i] != null)
            {
                stack1.Push(t.c[i]);
                TreeNode rchild = new TreeNode(t.c[i].mystringdata );
                r.Nodes.Add(rchild);
                stack2.Push(rchild);
            }
        }               
    }
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a custom node class to a TreeNode, you can write a simple recursive [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Assuming you have a class like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; } = new List<Node>();
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Node(string data)
    {
        this.Text = data;
    }
}
```

Then you can write a simple recursive extension method like the following:

```
public static class NodeExtensions
{
    public static TreeNode ToTreeNode(this Node node)
    {
        var treeNode = new TreeNode(node.Text);
        foreach (Node child in node.Nodes)
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(child.ToTreeNode());
        return treeNode;
    }
}
```

Later, to use it to populate a TreeView:

```
var node = new Node("1");
node.Nodes.Add(new Node("1-1"));
node.Nodes.Add(new Node("1-2"));
node.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new Node("1-1-1"));
node.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new Node("1-2-1"));
node.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new Node("1-2-2"));

treeView1.Nodes.Add(node.ToTreeNode());
```

To see a general solution to populate a TreeView based on a DataTable or any list which contains tree-like data, take a look at: [Populate TreeView from DataTable or List that contains tree-like data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924862/3110834)

**More information:**

- [How to implement and call a custom extension method (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)